# How to express less information than a uniform probability distribution function?

Tags: probability-distributions, information-theory

Suppose you have a discrete finite set of possible outcomes, say $x_i,\,i=1\ldots n$. And *"information"* here means what you can say about which outcome will occur. That would typically be represented by some probability distribution function, say $\rho(i)$, with the usual constraints. And then the least information (maximum entropy) you could have would be represented by the uniform distribution $\forall i: \rho(i)=\frac1n$.

But suppose you don't even know that, *i.e.*, you don't even know the pdf characterizing the $x_i$ outcomes. You might suggest a pdf over the space of pdfs, but such a *"second-order pdf"* still reduces to a pdf. So how can you formally/rigorously express less information than a uniform distribution, where you don't even know the distribution to begin with? Because knowing the distribution is still knowing something. So, also, how would you represent "no information", what would it mathematically mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a Partition of the Universe , that is , make Sets $X_i$ where every Pair will have no common element , with the Union being the Original Set $Y$.

$\Cup X_i = Y$

Now assign Probability of a Set $P(X_i) = |X_i|/|Y|$

This is very Close to uniform Distribution but has less information because we are not assigning Probability to each element.

In Extreme Case, make $X_1$ & $X_2$ have equal elements(or maybe $X_1$ has 1 more than $X_2$) where $X_1 \cup X_2 = Y$

$P(X_1) \approx P(X_2) \approx 1/2$
This will have very less information.

Eventually , make it $P(Y)=1$ which has no information !

Comment: Thanks, @Prem, but I'm thinking we could maybe even more generally, and even less informationally (except for the $P(Y)=1$ case), not demand a partition. We could have overlapping sets $X_i$ as long as we still have $\bigcup X_i=Y$. Consider, _e.g._, your $X_1\cup X_2=Y$, where $Y=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and $X_1=\{a,b,c,d\},\ X_2=\{c,d,e\}$. Then we could (we'd have to) assign probabilities that add to more than $1$, and I think (but am not sure) our ability to infer probabilities for individual outcomes could be even weaker than for partitions. What do you think? And how do we calculate entropies?

Comment: That will not generate less Probability : When we have Common Elements , we can calculate the Probability of those Common Elements by Union & Intersection , which will then enable calculating the Probability of the other Elements in each Set , in which case it will come back to Partition Case !

Comment: Okay, thanks again. But I was thinking (but could again be wrong) that the probability of a union wouldn't necessarily be the sum of its component probabilities, and similarly for intersection/product, depending on how you constructed the (overlapping) decomposition. And in such a case there might not be any "equivalent" partition that gives identical information.

Comment: $P(1,2,3)=3/4$ & $P(2,3,4)=3/4$ will give $P(2,3)=P(1,2,3)+P(2,3,4)-P(1,2,3,4)=3/4+3/4-1=1/2$ which will give $P(1)=3/4-1/2=1/4$ & $P(4)=3/4-1/2=1/4$ which will give Partition P = [ [1],[2,3],[4] ] !!

Comment: Thanks for the example; guess I've been wrong about that. I'll have to do some pencil-and-paper work of my own to intuitively see the general case for myself. Thanks, again, for the answer and comments.

Comment: This should made more objective by computing the amount of information by $\sum p_i \ln(p_i)$

Comment: We have made that so uncertain ( with so less information ) , that we do not know Individual $P_i$ [[ we know only $P(X_i)$ , where Each $X_i$ might have multiple Elements ]] hence we can not get that Exact Value , @JeanMarie

Comment: @JeanMarie and Prem: Yeah, I asked about calculating entropy at the very end of my first comment above, as I'm ultimately interested in constructing some information-based poset relation on this structure (maybe even a lattice, if possible). But as prem says, simply applying $-\sum p_i\ln(p_i)$ to a partition ignores the cardinalities of the subsets comprising the partition. And it seemed clear to me that you can't just weight each term in the sum by its subset cardinality. Now, we can easily construct a poset for partitions alone. But what to do when you apply pdfs to them??? Any ideas?